# Quote conflict in JS when parsing to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, json, parsing

So I have this JSON object I need to parse into a string and send to my SQL database using JavaScript. Node package is 'mysql'. JSON object is an array of objects with variable amount of keys and looks like this:

```json
{
    array:
        [
            {"title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet: <a href=\ "https:\/\/www.google.com\/">'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'<\/a>
                    The future of aviation doesn't necessarily involve existing aircraft..."
            }
        ],
        [...],
        [...]
}
```

I parse it using following methods:

```js
let values = [];
let elements = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    values = [];
    for (let key in array[i]) {
        values.push(`"${array[i][key]}"`)
    }
    elements.push(`(${values.join(', ')})`)
}
// pushing elements and columns into an sql query 
let sql = `INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES ${elements.join(', ')}`
```

When I attempt to query the string it returns the following error:

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual ...",
sqlState: '42000',
```

I blame quotes and apostrophes as this parsing method worked with another JSON object I've had.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You're right, i'm sorry. I wish i could post the original JSON file in public but for privacy reasons i had to replace it.

Comment: Thank you! But how would you parse it after converting an object to string? I don't really understand your solution. I worked with JSON object to extract multiple values since i have to put "title" and "body" keys as table columns and their values as table values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle serialization of your json object using `JSON.stringify()` method. You need not write your own function for this

Similarly for deserialization use `JSON.parse()` to convert your string back to JSON object